# How to Save a dataframe in mongoDB using Apache spark and java library

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a csv file ..I load it to program using Sql Context and it upload it a dataframe.Now i want to store this csv file into mongodbCollection.And i am not able to convert it in to JavaPairedRDD.Please Help...

My Code is...

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;    
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;    
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;    
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;    
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;    
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;    
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;    
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;    
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;    
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata;    
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;    
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;    
import org.bson.BSONObject;    
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;    
import com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat;

public class CSVReader {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sparkConnection").setMaster("local");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

        /* To load a csv file frol given location*/

        DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()

                .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")

                .option("inferSchema", "true")//Automaticaaly infers the data 

                .option("header", "true")//To include the headers in dataframe

                .load("D:/SparkFiles/abc.csv");

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You clearly haven't researched enough.

Because if you would have, you would know dataframe is a nothing but a combination of schema+ rdd.

Assuming your posted code works fine, you can read the rdd from df as `df.rdd`